# Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

My previous question is not clear. So I'm going to repeat it.

The label on the right part are the transmuted grade and the textbox is the raw score percentage.

How do I do a short way for this codes (**where I will not repeat it again in other textboxes**)

Dim grade as Integer

This codes will be in the button so when pressed, the raw percentage will be transformed to transmuted grade.

```
If MathTextbox.Text = "100" then MathLabel.Text= "1"
```

Codes like this, my prob is how do I avoid repeating it in each texboxes.

Comment: pass the 2 controls to a method which has "code like that".

Comment: Not a good approach. The button press is essentially a "divide by 100" operation.

Comment: `"My previous question is not clear."` - And you think this one is?  Show the code that you're using and explain how that code isn't doing what you expect it to do.  If there's some code style or practice that you're attempting to avoid, demonstrate it so we can see what the problem is.  Instead of vaguely describing what your code kind of looks like, you can actually add code to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you want **one button** to perform the same action to **multiple controls** then you can do something like this:

```
For Each ctrl1 As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (ctrl1) Is TextBox Then
        For Each ctrl2 As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf (ctrl2) Is Label AndAlso _
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(ctrl1.Name, 4) _
            = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Left(ctrl2.Name, 4) Then
                ctrl2.Text = ctrl1.Text
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Note that there are much better ways for identifying which label pairs with which textbox (I prefer [the `Tag` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) myself) and that if you're going to perform a numerical operation on a string (such as a textbox's `Text` property) you should validate it first, e.g. with [IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx).